# Unable to print directory list in a column with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working script that will print directory using scandir in a column. I am successfully able scan the directory and see the files but all in one line.
The end result that I am try to get to is to print then in a column by adding two addition for loops. 
Any help to steer me in the right direction will be appreciated.

```
import os
import re

path = "//xdrive/workdir/"
dirs = os.scandir(path)


dlis=[]
for file in dirs:
    dlis.append(file)
    for row in dlis:
        for item in row:
            print(item)
        print("")
```

This is what I get if I don't add for loop and add the following print statement.

```
    print(dlis)
```

```
`[<DirEntry 'web_2019-02-06.tar.gz'>, <DirEntry 'web_2019-02-07.tar.gz'>,       <DirEntry 'web_2019-02-09.tar.gz'>,<DirEntry 'web_2019-02-10.tar.gz'>, <DirEntry 'web_2019-02-10.tar.gz'>]
```

`
This is the end result I am work to get.

```
web_2019-02-06.tar.gz
web_2019-02-07.tar.gz
web_2019-02-09.tar.gz
web_2019-02-10.tar.gz
web_2019-02-10.tar.gz
```

This is the error that I am getting.

```
File "Backup_list.py", line 13, in <module>
    for item in row:
TypeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the output you are currently getting, and also an example of the output you are expecting.

Comment: Your code does not work at all because the `os.scandir` method returns `os.DirEntry` objects rather than file names. Also there's no need for a nested `for` loop.

Comment: @blhsing The nested <pre>for</pre> loop was to print out the results in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os.scandir` method returns [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects rather than file names. You should either use the `name` attribute of the object, or use the `os.listdir` method instead since you don't need the other attributes of the files. Also, there is no need for a nested `for` loop since you can simply iterate through the file names and print each file name on a separate line:

```
for file in os.scandir(path):
    print(file.name)
```

or:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: That did the trick. I never seen the .name used before in a print statement.